# Remove all grid lines in ios-charts

Tags: ios-charts

I already have

```
let chartView = LineChartView()
chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
chartView.drawBordersEnabled = false
```

This chart is simply sample data:

```
let values = (0..<30).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
   let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(420) + 3)
   return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
}
```

I simply want a line graph here with no scale or delimiting at all

[image: still shows x scale]

Answer (score 18):

Remove the vertical grid lines by hiding the gridlines on the xAxis:

```
chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

Remove the x Axis line and y Axis:

```
chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
chartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
```

This will result in a line chart that is just a line without any units or scale:

[image]

Comment: Worked great, thanks.  Ended up with:

let chartView = LineChartView()

chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false

chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
chartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false

chartView.drawBordersEnabled = false
chartView.legend.form = .none